# Completion in NSTextView

Tags: autocomplete, nstextview, code-completion

I am looking for a way (or code) to have a completion list close to the one of xcode 
[image: xcode completion]

Do you know how to achieve this?

Thanks and regards,

Answer (score 8):

Use the

```
- (NSArray *)textView:(NSTextView *)textView completions:(NSArray *)words forPartialWordRange:(NSRange)charRange indexOfSelectedItem:(NSInteger *)index
```

method of NSTextViewDelegate. This is called whenever text completion is initiated (either by the user, by pressing Esc or F5, or programmatically, by calling `-[NSTextView complete:]`.

You'll need to do some fancy overriding to make it look like the one in Xcode, however. The stock implementation displays only plain text in the system font.

Comment: Override -[NSTextView complete:], call the delegate method to get the possible completions, and then show a custom view with those contents.

Comment: Hi, which custom view, for example?

Comment: Depends on what you want to improve in what Cocoa supplies by default.